# Using jquery plugin select2 with bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I am trying to use `select2`, but I can't.

I am using the following code in my `<head>` section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="select2-bootstrap.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

and this is my `HTML` and `JS` Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('locationMultiple').select2({
    theme: "bootstrap"
});
</script>

<p>
<select class="locationMultiple form-control" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1d4h7g">Abondance (74360)</option>
  <option value="lf9k9d">Alby-Sur-Cheran (74540)</option>
  ...
</select>
</p>
```

But my select desperately stays as multiple rows.
Can any one help me to know where and what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Check if there is any error in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Code definitely work for you...

**You need to write this code in Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.select2.defaults.set("theme", "bootstrap");
    $(".locationMultiple").select2({
         width: null
    })
});
```

Live Example : https://jsfiddle.net/rajnikpatel/1vje5rxo/

Comment: please make sure you add right css path of `select2-bootstrap.css`

Comment: @Laurent - I think just moving your select2 js code inside $(document).ready() Or moving it to body last will work ( if calling js code before select element). Also check browser console if there is any error

Comment: you forgot to add `. (dot)` in JS code before `locationMultiple` for accessing your select2 control

Comment: Thanks to all, Yes I saw the dot, but it's not that, path is good and there are no errors inloading neither in scripts. I have also tried to remove all other scripts piwik, cookieConsent and shareThis, but still the same... I'll continue to investigate

Comment: Whole would be quite long ;-) I have even tried with just the content of your fiddle and it's still the same.

Comment: So... I have found, helped with both of you, I just need to enclose the initialization of the select in $(document).ready(function ($). @Rajnik, can you update your solution ? Thanks !!!